# $A+B+C+D=\pi$, and $0\leq A,B,C,D \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Prove that $\sin^4(A)+\sin^4(B)+\sin^4(C)+\sin^4(D)\leq 2$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangle-inequality

I tried to simplify it from some ways.
(1).$\sin^4(A)+\sin^4(B)+\sin^4(C)+\sin^4(D)$
$=\left(\frac{1-\cos(2A)}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1-\cos(2B)}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1-\cos(2C)}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1-\cos(2D)}{2}\right)^2$
$=1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(2A)+\cos(2B)+\cos(2C)+\cos(2D)\right)+\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(2+\frac{\cos(4A)+\cos(4B)+\cos(4C)+\cos(4D)}{2}\right)$
$=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(2A)+\cos(2B)+\cos(2C)+\cos(2D)\right)+\frac{1}{8}\left(\cos(4A)+\cos(4B)+\cos(4C)+\cos(4D)\right)$
(2).$\cos(2A)+\cos(2B)+\cos(2C)+\cos(2D)$
$=2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)+2\cos(C+D)\cos(C-D)$
since $A+B=\pi-(C+D)$, thus $\cos(A+B)=-\cos(C+D)$. It follows that
$=2\cos(A+B)\left(\cos(A-B)-\cos(C-D)\right)$
$=2\cos(A+B)\cdot\left(-2\sin(\frac{A-B+C-D}{2})\sin(\frac{A-B-C+D}{2})\right)$
$=2\cos(A+B)\cdot\left(-2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-(B+D)\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-(B+C)\right)\right)$
$=2\cos(A+B)\cdot\left(-2\cos(B+D)\cos(B+C)\right)$
$=-4\cos(A+B)\cos(A+C)\cos(A+D)$
(3).Similarly,$\cos(4A)+\cos(4B)+\cos(4C)+\cos(4D)$
$=2\cos(2A+2B)\cos(2A-2B)+2\cos(2C+2D)\cos(2C-2D)$
$=2\cos(2A+2B)\cos(2A+2C)\cos(2A+2D)$
Am I on the right track? Maybe it is a Jensen's-inequality problem but it seems not always concave up or down in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. I am stuck here. Please help, and thank you.

Comment: Is it a contest problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Remark i)*: The desired inequality is still true without the condition $A, B, C, D \le \pi/2$.

*Remark ii)*: According to my proof, for $A + B + C + D = \pi$, we have the following identity:
\begin{align*}
 &2 - \sin^4 A - \sin^4 B - \sin^4 C - \sin^4 D \\
 =\, & \sin^2 (A - B) \cos^2 (A + B)
 + \frac12(\cos (A + B) + \cos (A - B))^2\\
 &\quad  + 2\cos(C + D)\sin C \sin D 
 + \sin^2 C\cos^2 C + \sin^2 D \cos^2 D.
\end{align*}

---

$\phantom{2}$

**Problem 1**: Let $A, B, C, D \ge 0$ with $A + B + C + D = \pi$. Prove that
$$\sin^4 A + \sin^4 B + \sin^4 C + \sin^4 D \le 2.$$

**Proof**:

WLOG, assume that $A \ge B \ge C \ge D$.

Clearly, $C + D \le \pi/2$. We have (See Remark 1 at the end for details)
$$\sin^2 (C + D) - \sin^2 C - \sin^2 D
= 2\cos (C + D) \sin C \sin D \ge 0. \tag{1}$$
Thus, we have
$$\sin^4 C + \sin^4 D
\le \sin^2 C + \sin^2 D \le \sin^2 (C + D).$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\sin^4 A + \sin^4 B + \sin^2(C + D) \le 2$$
or
$$\sin^4 A + \sin^4 B + \sin^2(A + B) \le 2$$
which is written as (see Remark 2 at the end for details)
$$\sin^2 (A - B) \cos^2 (A + B)
+ \frac12(\cos (A + B) + \cos (A - B))^2 \ge 0. \tag{2}$$

We are done.

---

$\phantom{2}$

Remark 1: We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sin^2(C + D) - \sin^2 C - \sin^2 D\\
 =\,& \frac{1 - \cos (2C + 2D)}{2} - \frac{1 - \cos 2C}{2} - \sin^2 D\\
 =\,& \frac{\cos 2C - \cos (2C + 2D)}{2} - \sin^2 D\\
 =\,& \sin (2C + D) \sin D - \sin^2 D\\
 =\,& (\sin (2C + D) - \sin D)\sin D\\
 =\,& 2\cos (C + D) \sin C \sin D.
\end{align*}

$\phantom{2}$

Remark 2: Let $u = A + B, v = A - B$ (correspondingly, $A = \frac{u + v}{2}, B = \frac{u - v}{2}$). We have
\begin{align*}
 &2 - \sin^4 A - \sin^4 B - \sin^2(A + B)\\
 =\,& 2 - \left(\frac{1 - \cos (u + v)}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1 - \cos (u - v)}{2}\right)^2 - \sin^2 u\\
 =\,& \frac{3}{2} - \frac{\cos^2(u + v) + \cos^2 (u - v)}{4} + \frac{\cos(u + v) + \cos (u - v)}{2} - \sin^2 u \\
 =\,& \frac{3}{2} - \frac{\cos^2 u \cos^2 v + \sin^2 u \sin^2 v}{2} + \cos u \cos v - \sin^2 u \\
 =\,& - \cos^2 u \cos^2 v + \frac{1}{2}\cos^2 v + \frac{3}{2}\cos^2 u + \cos u \cos v \\
 =\,& \cos^2 u \sin^2 v + \frac12(\cos u + \cos v)^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Unbelievable trigonometric identity! Thank you very much.

Comment: May I ask that how to get that $\sin^2(x+y)-\sin^2(x)-\sin^2(y)=2\sin(x)\sin(y)\cos(x+y)$?

Comment: $\sin^2(x+y)-\sin^2(x)-\sin^2(y)=\sin(2x+y)\sin(y)-\sin^2(y)=\sin(y)\left[\sin(2x+y)-\sin(y)\right]=\sin(y)\cdot\left[2\cos(x+y)\sin(x)\right]$, ok, I got it!

Comment: I'm so sorry. May I ask again the simplified process of $2-\sin^4(x)-\sin^4(y)-\sin^2(x+y)=\sin^2(x-y)\cos^2(x+y)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)\right)^2$

Comment: @余志祥 You proved the first one. For the second one, you may let $u = x + y, v = x - y$ and simplify it to an expression involving $\cos u$ and $\cos v$, using $\sin^2 a = \frac{1 - \cos 2a}{2}$ etc.

Comment: @余志祥 I added some details for these two.

Comment: Yes, I read it. I'm so appreciate that. I learn a lot! Thank you for your help again.

Comment: @余志祥 You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an ugly solution and would love a clever one.

First, let's assume wlog $D \le C \le B \le A$ and then $D+C \le \pi/2$ and we show that $\sin^4C+\sin^4D \le \sin^4(C+D)$ so we reduce the problem to three angles where we use calculus.

Noting that $\sin^2x-\sin^2y=\sin(x-y)\sin(x+y)$, one has $\sin^4(C+D)-\sin^4C=(\sin^2(C+D)+\sin^2C)\sin D \sin (2C+D)$ and since $C+D \le \pi/2$ then $D \le \pi-(2C+D)$ and $D \le 2C+D$ so $\sin D \le \sin (2C+D)=\sin (\pi-(2C+D))$ since $\sin$ is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$. Since $\sin^2D \le \sin^2C$ by the same reason, one gets that $\sin^4D \le \sin^2C \sin D\sin (2C+D) \le (\sin^2(C+D)+\sin^2C)\sin D \sin (2C+D)$ and we are done with the reduction.

Now with $A+B+C =\pi, 0 \le A,B,C \le \pi/2$ we consider the function $f(x,y)=\sin^4x+\sin^4y+\sin^4(x+y)$ and show that it has only one critical point (at $x=y=\pi/3, (f(x,y)=27/16$) inside the triangle $0 \le x,y, \pi-x-y \le \pi/2$ while on the boundary at least one of $x,y,x+y=\pi/2$ and then if wlog $x+y=\pi/2$ we can apply the result in the first paragraph, hence $\sin^4x+\sin^4y \le \sin^4(x+y)=1$ (or directly as $\sin^4x+\sin^4y=\sin^4x+\cos^4x\le \sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$) so the maximum of $f$ on the closed triangle (which exists as $f$ continous) is $2$ so we are done!

So looking at $f_x=f_y=0$ we get $\sin^3x\cos x+\sin^3(x+y)\cos (x+y)=\sin^3y\cos y+\sin^3(x+y)\cos (x+y)=0$ or with the original notation $\sin^3A\cos A=\sin^3B\cos B=\sin^3C\cos C$

But now $g(x)=\sin^3x \cos x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$ has $g'(x)=3\sin^2x\cos^2x-\sin^4x=3\sin^2x-4\sin^4x$, so $g'$ has clearly only one zero at $x=\pi/3$ and $g'>0$ on $(0, \pi/3)$, while $g'<0$ on $(\pi/3,\pi/2)$ hence $g$ monotonic (so injective) on each of the two intervals, which implies that at least two of $A,B,C$ must be equal and wlog let $A=B=x$ hence from $f_x=f_y=0$ we get $\sin^3x\cos x=-\sin^3(2x)\cos(2x)$ which (since $2x \ge \pi/2$) gives $\cos x= -8\cos^3 x\cos (2x)$; but now we are inside $(0, \pi/2)$ so $\cos x \ne 0$ either, hence $1=-4(1+\cos 2x)\cos 2x$ or $\cos 2x=-1/2, x=\pi/3$ and our claim about critical points is proven and the problem solved!

Comment: wow, your solution is clever too! thanks for your help~

Comment: but it seems that $\sin^4(C+D)-\sin^4(C)=\left(\sin^2(C+D)+\sin^2(C)\right)\sinD\sin(2C+D)$.

Comment: oops - corrected (nothing changes in the argument as the crucial fact is that if $C+D \le \pi/2$ then $\sin D \le \sin (2C+D)$ which if $C+D > \pi/2$ may not be true)

Comment: this being said a clever (geometric/trigonometric) proof in the triangle case would be nice as that is the difficult case where the reducing trick (which is what comes to mind immediately when an inequality turns equal on the boundary rather than inside) doesn't work directly

Comment: @Conrad The first step is nice. (+1)

Comment: @River it would be nice if the result for three angles could be proved directly as calculus works but it's not elegant here

Comment: @Conrad By the way, it seems the inequality is true for all $A, B, C, D \ge 0$ with $A + B + C + D = \pi$, i.e. without the condition $A, B, C, D \le \pi/2$.

Comment: @River - yes because the first reduction works as before since there is always a pair which sums to at most $90$ but then if you have three angles and two sum to at most $90$ you can reduce again to two and for those it is trivial; the hard case is three angles summing in pairs to more than $90$ (in other words $A+B \le \pi/2$ implies $\sin^4A+\sin^4 \le \sin^4(A+B)$ which is clearly not true in general if $A+B > \pi/2$)

Comment: @River what I suspect to be true but do not see how to prove without calculus is that if $\pi \ge A+B > \pi/2$ then $\sin^4A+\sin^4B \le 1+\sin^4(A+B-\pi/2)=1+\cos^4(A+B)$ which of course would prove the result for three angles